# Laravel 5.4 Passport Log user action (Optional auth:api)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I am using Laravel Passport (`auth:api`), all works well however I've came with the idea to log record user requests on a specific route.

When an `GET` request is made to `/movie/65` I would like to store in `movie_view` the following data: `user_id`, `movie_id` (if the user is logged in)

However in my controller I am unable to call `$request->user()` without setting `auth:api` middleware.

What is the best practice you recommend to achieve this?

Comment: Just to mention, this is done not for security reasons but to describe on how `popular` is the movie by views recorded.

Comment: What I actually need is `Optional auth:api` - is that possible in laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default Auth Type should be set to 'api' in `config/auth.php`

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/optional-authentication-for-api?page=0 (it was very hard to find)

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this is:

```
if (\Auth::guard('api')->check()) {
    $user = \Auth::guard('api')->user();
}
```

you have to setup the guard to 'api', the default one is 'web'.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom middleware as suggested here -- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-handle-route-with-optional-authentication. Then apply `api` guard to it. Let say you assign that custom middleware as `auth.optional` in `Kernel.php`, then you can use that middleware as `auth.optional:api` (with that `api` guard). Then you can access user thru `$request->user()` in your case above.